# UTF8 urls doesn't work in nginx+passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicode, utf-8, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get working UTF8 routes in rails 4

```
get '/документы', to: 'static_pages#docs', as: :docs
```

Its working great on a WEBrick, but doesn't work in a battlefield (nginx+passenger)

I guess its because nginx makes my url lowercase

```
No route matches [GET] "/%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b"
```

but rails expects it to be uppercase

```
Started GET "/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B" for 127.0.0.1
Completed 200 OK in 52ms (Views: 49.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

**Is there any way to make the nginx to understand unicode routes?**

heres my nginx server config

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name website.com;

   charset utf8;

   root /web/website/public;

   location ~ ^/assets/ {
      root /web/website/public;
      expires 1y;
      add_header Cache-Control public;#
      add_header ETag "";
      break;
   }

   error_page  502 404 /502.html;

   passenger_enabled on;
   rails_spawn_method smart;
   rails_env production;
 }
```

Comment: "nginx makes my url lowercase" I don't understand, Nginx doesn't do anything to your URLS, it just passes requests that it receives to the backend. Presumably the browser is requesting the URL as lower case?

Comment: I'm using the same browser for WEBrick and nginx

Comment: Apache with Passenger does the same. Any luck fixing this?